# Can't build Haskell/Postgres project using Docker on OS X

Tags: postgresql, haskell, docker

I'm trying to build and run Haskell project with Docker. Project contains PSQL-databases. 
When I write run-command `docker run project_name /usr/local/bin/project_name`, so I get:

```
    $ docker run carma-bundle /usr/local/bin/carma
no port specified, defaulting to port 8000
carma:
Initializer threw an exception...
libpq: failed (could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
)

...but before it died it generated the following output:
Initializing app @ /
Initializing heist @ /heist
...loaded 0 templates from /srv/snaplets/heist
...adding 1 templates from resources/static/tpl with route prefix //
Initializing CookieSession @ /session
Initializing postgresql-simple @ /db
Initializing postgresql-auth @ /auth
...setting up filesystem
```

Additional info:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.16

$ stack --numeric-version
1.4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

This is telling you that on localhost, within your container, there is no postgres running.

Each container has its own localhost address. They are separate from localhost in other containers, and separate from the localhost address on the main system where Docker is running.